# DeWalt nail gun leaks air when trigger is pulled

Tags: powertools

DeWalt D51257 has been lightly used for home projects but it stopped working. When trigger is pulled, only air is coming out (through the trigger area) but no nail is fired. Should I replace the trigger valve? Cylinder and o-rings looks ok. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Checked, found nothing blocking... one thing I noticed was when I engage the safety lock, I can hear small amount of air leaking there.

Comment: Did you open the front to expose the drive pin to see if it is retracted entirely? If it does not retract entirely it will leak air when the trigger is pulled. I have had nails jam behind it and keep it from retracting and had to pull it up by hand exposing the nail behind it. Disconnect the air before doing so.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thought. I opened the top and took out the cylinder and the piston. I don't think there was a nail stuck inside. I suspect the O-rings are bad?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem with my D51257. Used about  10 years ago and when I tried to nail this  past  weekend shot two nails  and stopped. Problem was the trigger valve, three O-Rings are gum type  rubber and  over time  these dry out  and  disintegrate just like a gum rubber band.  I ordered a replacement trigger valve from Amazon and will replace the valve in a few days. In the meantime,  I went to Ace Hardware and bought three O-Rings and after sanding the trigger shaft O-Rings down to fit in the trigger cylinder, I reinstalled the trigger and nailer works  fine. Will keep new trigger on hand for future use.

Comment: You should seal up the replacement ring with multiple air-tight bags or it'll just dry out before you get to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on a Makita siding nailer. 1 week old, was working perfectly the day before. Checked that the piston wasn’t stuck, opened it to see if residue was affecting the o-ring; everything was fine. In frustration, I held the trigger down while pressing the nozzle against the material. After about 5 seconds the gun finally engaged. Working perfectly again.